# React Native Search Filter working for Android, not IOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, search, native, expo

Created a search function for a react-native app.  Works in Expo.  Distributed to test on Google Play and Apple.  The Android version works fine.  The IOS version does not filter any results.  See my code.  Seems pretty straight forward - no errors - but no updated list.

...
  searchFilterFunction = text => {
    this.setState({
      value: text
    });

```
let filteredData = this.props.navigation.state.params.animalList.filter(
  item => {
    return item.animalId.includes(text);
  }
);
this.setState({ filteredData: filteredData });};  renderHeader = () => {
return (
  <SearchBar
    placeholder="Search by ID..."
    placeholderTextColor={'white'}
    darkTheme
    containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#ccb266", marginLeft: -2, marginRight: -2 }}
    round
    icon={{ color: "white" }}
    onChangeText={text => this.searchFilterFunction(text)}
    autoCorrect={false}
    value={this.state.value}
  />
);
```

};

...

I expected the FlatList to update on IOS as it does on Android.

The FlatList is further down the code:

```
        <FlatList
      data={
        this.state.filteredData && this.state.filteredData.length > 0
          ? this.state.filteredData
          : this.props.navigation.state.params.animalList
      }
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: '#493e3a', marginLeft: 20, marginRight: 20}}
      extraData={this.props}
      ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}          
      style={styles.myFlatCard}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}          
      refreshControl={
        <RefreshControl
          refreshing={this.state.refresh}
          onRefresh={this._loadActiveList}
        />
      }
```

Comment: FlatList? What Flatlist?

Comment: Edited my question - the FlatList is further down in the code.